# ifconfig stats: where are they from?

Tags: linux, network-programming, kernel

With ifconfig, I can not only see ip addresses but also stats on the device. E.g.

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ac:22:0b:7f:fa:cf  
      inet addr:192.168.1.111  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::ae22:bff:fe7f:facf/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:767217 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:647481 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:880990453 (880.9 MB)  TX bytes:236143991 (236.1 MB)
```

I can see that the stats such as dropped, overrun, etc are read from kernel /proc/net/dev. My question is: how does the kernel get such information in the first place? Is it through internal accounting or hardware registers?

Answer (score 0):

The statistics are tracked through internal kernel data structures, as you suggest. The [Red Hat crash utility](http://people.redhat.com/anderson/crash_whitepaper/) is one way to explore those structures.